# How to control the address that the user enters and show 404

Tags: php, http-status-code-404

[image]

I want to show the 404 page when user enters unknown address like on the above image.

I can control the unknown address after `index.php` but don't know how to do this for the part before the `index.php` part.

I wrote this code to control what user enters after `index.php`

```php
<?php
$pageName = 'places';
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
$pageName = $_GET['page'];
}

$pageList = array(
    'places',
    'places_info',
    'save'
);

if (!in_array($pageName, $pageList)) {
$pageName = '404';
}
?>
```

Comment: In general, this needs to be done on a web server end. For Apache it will be `ErrorDocument 404 /my-404-page.php` (for example). You may also use [Apache's **mod_rewrite**](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/) rule to test if the requested resource does not exist and forward the request to your `index.php`.

Comment: In general -- if you look at any modern site/framework (WordPress/Drupal/Laravel/Symfony/etc -- they have a rule in their web server config where if a requested resource does not exist then use `index.php` to handle the request (and inside it then checks if it's a URL that they can handle or should they show 404 page).

Comment: @LazyOne  so its not possible to do it on localhost. OK I got it. thanks.

Comment: *"so its not possible to do it on localhost. OK I got it."* Why not? 1) Accordingly to a screenshot your page is served by Apache web server. 2) Apache can obviously run on a remote server as well as on your own computer. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errordocument

Comment: @LazyOne OK.I'll do.

Comment: Please show us your folder structure

Comment: @RohitGupta C:\xampp\htdocs\blit\index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have apache on your development machine.

The way to have custom error pages is

1. Create/Edit the file in **C:\xampp\htdocs\blit\.htaccess**
2. Insert a line **ErrorDocument 404 /blit/404.shtml**
3. Create the file **C:\xampp\htdocs\blit\404.shtml**
4. Put whatever html you want in it.
5. Repeat for other errors.

If you type in **localhost/blit/xxy** and **xxy.php** and **xxy.html** do not exist then the error page will be shown.

Comment: Here, thanks is shown by ticking it and upvoting it.  Which you already have.

Comment: yes I did. I wanted to thank in words too.

Comment: if I upload this .htaccess to real server, does it still work ? or any extra setting should be done in web server config

Comment: It will still work, if its apache.  But your server is hosted somewhere, their control software may allow you to do it easier, in a different way.  Regardless the error pages are identical.